# syntax of for loop in linux shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop, dash-shell

I have a problem implementing a for loop. I get this error when I execute my script

> test1.sh: 2: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable

I don't understand this error.

This is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( c=1; c<=5; c++ ))
do
echo "Welcome $c times..."
done
```

can any one tell me syntax for for loop in sh(in ubuntu it links to dash shell) shell in ubuntu?

Comment: I don't get the same error as you for that - I get unexpected end of file. Anyway, you have a missing semicolon.

Comment: That works for me. You probably have a weird character hidden in the text.

Comment: For bash the syntax seems fine. Can you try to make sure you're running the right shell ? `ls -l /bin/bash`, maybe ?

Comment: This works for me when you put the done statement on its own line.

Comment: I ran it using sh instead of bash. Works fine in bash. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You probably run it with `sh`, not `bash`. Try `bash test1.sh`, or `./test1.sh` if it's executable, but not `sh test1.sh`.

Comment: Works fine in bash as currently displayed in the post

Comment: Krelin: You are right. I ran it using sh instead of bash or "./". It works well now. Thanks

Comment: Yes works fine in bash. Make sh point to bash ( symbolic link) !

Answer (score 6):

A standard POSIX shell only accepts the syntax `for varname in list`

The C-like for-loop syntax `for (( expr1; expr2; expr3 ))` is a bashism.

You can get similar behavior in the standard POSIX shell using `for c in $(seq 1 5)`

Answer (score 1):

Your shell script (as shown) runs in both Korn shell and Bash. Some thoughts:

- You might need a space after the shebang (#! /bin/bash and not #!/bin/bash). However, Dennis Ritchie had originally specified the space is ***optional***. Besides, it isn't the error you get with Bourne shell (you get *`syntax error: '(' unexpected`* instead).
- Are you on a Windows system? Just a stab in the dark. This doesn't look like a Windows error.
- Is this Solaris or HP/UX system? They might not be running true versions of Bash, or maybe an older version. However, even the oldest version of Bash recognizes the `for ((x;y;z))` construct.

Try this:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -vx
echo "Random = $RANDOM"   #Test for bash/Kornshell. Will be blank in other shells
echo \$BASH_VERSINFO[0] = ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} #Should only work in BASH
echo \$BASH_VERSINFO[1] = ${BASH_VERSINFO[1]}
echo \$BASH_VERSINFO[2] = ${BASH_VERSINFO[2]}
echo \$BASH_VERSINFO[3] = ${BASH_VERSINFO[3]}
echo \$BASH_VERSINFO[4] = ${BASH_VERSINFO[4]}
echo \$BASH_VERSINFO[5] = ${BASH_VERSINFO[5]}
for ((c=0, c<=5, c++))
do
    echo "Welcome $c times"
done
```

- The `set -xv` will display all lines as they are executed.
- The `$RANDOM` should display a value if this is either BASH or Kornshell (your for loop will work in either one).
- The `{$BASH_VERINFO[x]}` should only be set if this is truly BASH. These aren't even set even if you run Korn shell after you're in BASH (unlike $SHELL which will still contain `bash`).

If the for loop still gives you trouble, just delete it. Somewhere in this script, we'll find out if you're really executing a bash shell or not.

Answer (score 1):

What does

```
ls -l /bin/sh
```

give on your machine ?

Make `sh` a symbolic link to `bash` and then you can do `sh ./test1.sh`