# Is this bash for loop statement correct?

Tags: bash, for-loop

Here's the code:

```
totLines=$(wc -l < extractedips.txt)
for((a=0;a!=$totLines;a++))
{
  head -n$a extractedips.txt | nslookup >> ip_extracted.txt
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Yes! Despite what people are saying, this is a valid bash `for` loop!

Note, however, that it's a bash extension. It's not a valid `sh` for loop. You can not use this form of loop in e.g. a shell script declared with `#!/bin/sh` or run with `sh yourscript`.

The thing that doesn't work is your for loop contents.

1. You're trying to get the n'th line, but `head -n 42` gets the first 42 lines, not line number 42.
2. You're using 0-based indexing, while `head` is 1-based.
3. You're piping to nslookup, but nslookup expects an argument and not stdin.

The shortest fix to your problem is:

```
totLines=$(wc -l < extractedips.txt)
for ((a=1; a<=totLines; a++)); do
    nslookup "$(head -n "$a" extractedips.txt | tail -n 1)" >> ip_extracted.txt
done
```

However, the more efficient and canonical way of doing it is with a while read loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  nslookup "$line"
done  < extractedips.txt  > ip_extracted.txt
```

Comment: OP, please use the last code of this answer, refered to as _the [...] canonical way of doing it is with a while read loop_.

Comment: This is it! I found the same thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627179/syntax-of-for-loop-in-linux-shell-scripting. I'm still tweaking the code to tailor it to a specific output, but that's it!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `do` and `done` instead of curly braces.

Like this:

```
totLines=$(wc -l < extractedips.txt)
for ((a=0; a!=totLines; a++)); do
    head -n "$a" extractedips.txt | nslookup >> ip_extracted.txt
done
```

However, this code will do some weird stuff... Are you trying to pass it line by line into nslookup ?

What about this?

```
nslookup < extractedips.txt > ip_extracted.txt
```

Or you might want this:

```
while read -r line; do
    nslookup "$line" >> ip_extracted.txt
done < extractedips.txt
```

Comment: Yea, that's the idea. To do a batch nslookup essentially.

Comment: @user3440108 then both of my suggestions should work. If you don't need any extra logic, then go with the shortest solution.

Answer (score -3):

Looks like you need sth. like this

```
for i in $(cat extractedips.txt)
do
echo $i | nslookup >> ip_extracted.txt
done
```

You don't need your counter variable, have a look at [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/) for a better understanding.

---

Why I think your statement is wrong/not what you want and my answer don't deserve a negative voting :)

This statement will echo the first $a lines inside file extractedips.txt

```
head -n$a extractedips.txt | nslookup >> ip_extracted.txt
```

First up you have a file with ip's

```
cat extractedips.txt
127.0.0.1
192.168.0.1
173.194.44.88
```

Now we if you do

```
for a in 1 2 3
    head -n$a
done
```

the script will output

```
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
192.168.0.1
127.0.0.1
192.168.0.1
173.194.44.88
```

But I guess you need a list with all all ip's only once. If you don't need duplicate ip's you could also remove them. This will give you a sorted list with duplicates removed.

```
for a in $(sort test.txt | uniq -u)
do
echo $a | nslookup >> ip_extracted.txt
done
```

**Update**

As Aleks commented this will not work if the text file contain a '*' char. The shell will expand all files in current directory and echo the filename. I didn't know that :/

Comment: That's not how you read a file line by line, have a look at [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for a better understanding.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko yes you are right. But for small text files you can also use my approach. Please give it a try, it'll work.

Comment: no, it does not "work". Place ``*`` into your file and see how it breaks :)