# Replacing bash arrays and C-style for loops in POSIX sh

Tags: bash, sh

I want to convert following bash code in pure shell script (sh) language so that it should run by other script language mode i.e dash script.

```
arguments=("$@")
for (( i=0; i<$#; i++ )); do
  case "${arguments[$i]}" in
    -foo)
    let "i = i + 1"
    echo "${arguments[$i]}"
      ;;
    *)                                                                                        
      break
  esac
done
```

above code finely run in bash mode but through an error on dash mode.

```
2: ./orig.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Now If I change line 2 to get rid the error as following line

```
arguments="$@"
```

But now I got another error about loop

```
 3: ./orig.sh: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
```

Comment: What error are you getting from dash exactly?

Comment: you can see that error just starting a script file with #!/bin/dash

Comment: If I had a machine with dash handy I'm sure I could do that. I don't. You do and you are asking the question.

Comment: If a run that script on dash I got '2: ./orig.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5627818

Comment: We aren't a free code translation service. If you asked how to convert from bash to Python, you'd get downvoted and closed for that too.

Comment: ...that said, I've tried to edit the question to be a bit more on-topic.

Comment: The code you actually posted could be replaced with `[ "$1" = "-foo" ] && echo "$2"`. No loop needed at all, since the loop terminates as soon as it sees the first non-`-foo` argument.

Answer (score 4):

POSIX sh doesn't support arrays or C-style for loops.

```
i=0
while [ $(( ( i += 1 ) <= 10 )) -ne 0 ]; do
  eval "val=\$$i"
  case "$val" in
    -foo)
      i=$(( i + 1 ))
      eval "val=\$$i"
      echo "$val"
      ;;
    *)                                                                                        
      break
  esac
done
```

Comment: The `echo` should output the argument following `-foo`, not `-foo` itself.

Comment: Thanks (and for the reassurance as well); should now be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

The POSIX way to handle the arguments is to consume them using `shift` while `$#` is non-zero.

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case $1 in
      -foo)
        echo "$2"
        shift; shift
        ;;
      *)
        break ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: I suddenly feel very silly for doing a literal translation rather than looking at intent.

Comment: I debated posting this or just commenting on your answer.  Yours is non-destructive and preserves the value of i where processing left off, so I think both are useful in different contexts.

Comment: Fair enough; retracted my self-deletion. :)

Comment: One minor correction; the `> 0` should be `-gt 0`. (Quoting the echo wouldn't hurt either).

Answer (score -2):

Now I have a Answer of my question, something like following works for me.

```
arguments="$@"
for i in $@; do
  case "$1" in
    -foo)
    shift 2
    echo "$1"
      ;;
    *)                                                                                        
      break
  esac
done
```

Comment: Don't ever do `arguments="$@"` in a POSIX shell -- it won't behave the way you expect. Compare the way it works when your script is run with `-foo "hello world"` and the way it works when your script is called with `-foo hello world`; the original bash script handled the former case, in particular, correctly.

Comment: also, using `$@` unquoted -- as you do here -- makes it behave the same way as unquoted `$*`, with all the pitfalls and caveats of that usage (stemming, principally, from string-splitting and glob expansion). Moreover, you don't even _need_ a for loop at all -- `while [ $# -gt 0 ]` would be more correct!

Comment: A good test, by the way, would be to see whether `./yourscript -foo "hello * world"` prints `hello * world` as it should -- that would catch both string splitting and glob expansion behavior.

Comment: This will also fail if you forget the second argument; `shift 2` will do nothing if there aren't two arguments to shift.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Hi, then what is the POSIX shell way to write the expression `arguments="$@"`

Comment: @EquationSolver, there *is* no POSIX shell way to write that expression, since POSIX has no way to store an array (a list of separate arguments) in a single variable while preserving the original delimiters.

Comment: ...this shouldn't be surprising -- if POSIX sh were as expressive as bash, there would have been no need for bash to have created extensions in the first place.