# How to read argument value inside for loop range for shell scripting

Tags: shell, parsing, for-loop, arguments

For loop looks like

```
for i in {1..n}
do
...
done
```

Instead of fixed n I want to read it from arguments. How do I do it? I tried putting $1 instead of n but it didnt work.

Comment: Since you're using brace expansion, I assume you use Bash and don't require POSIX conformity? For the latter, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26529255/replacing-bash-arrays-and-c-style-for-loops-in-posix-sh

Comment: This is also [BashPitfalls #33](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D).