# Syntax error:Bad for loop variable

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/bash

Clear
for ((row=1;row<=5;row++))
do
     for((col=1;col<=row;col++))
     do
          echo -n "$row "
     done
     echo "  "
done
```

I use kali Linux.  When I try to run this script then error show me.

> Pra20: 3: pra20: Syntax error:Bad for loop variable

Answer (score 1):

The message comes from `dash`, which is used as `sh` on some Linux's.  Therefore you are using `dash`, which does not support this syntax.

With the assumption that your script name is `Pra20`, you are probably running your script like this:

```
sh Pra20
```

instead of:

```
bash Pra20
```

or

```
./Pra20
```

Only the final method will read the `#!` line.  Also ensure you have execute access with `chmod u+x Pra20`.

See also: [syntax of for loop in linux shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627179/syntax-of-for-loop-in-linux-shell-scripting)

Answer (score 0):

`for loop` syntax used in your code is not supported by `shell(sh)` that's why  It's showing the error.

to solve this problem, either first make the script as `executable` and then `run` as

```
chmod  +x  kali.sh
./kali.sh
```

Otherwise use below `for loop` syntax

```
for var_name in test
do
         body of for loop
done
```

above syntax is supported by `sh` shell so you can run your script as `sh kali.sh`